# Webpack ignores webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack-4

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/) because I'm new with Webpack... My webpack.config.js is:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/entry",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "pruebaWebpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0"
  }
}
```

But apparently It's ignoring my config file because when I run `npm run build` It uses default paths (entry = ./src y output = ./dist) and doesn't recognize the mode attribute:

> pruebaWebpack@1.0.0 build /opt/lampp/htdocs/pruebaWebpack
>
> webpack
>
> Hash: 4a9c3de0f194dd38ac70 Version: webpack 4.4.1
>
> Time: 234ms
>
> Built at: 2018-4-1 15:53:00   Asset       Size  Chunks
>   Chunk
>
> Names main.js  564 bytes       0  [emitted]  main Entrypoint main =
>   main.js    [0] ./src/index.js 19 bytes {0} [built]
>
> WARNING in configuration The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack
>   will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to
>   'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
>   You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn
>   more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English.

Comment: It's odd that using a `webpack.config.js` file in your project root isn't working.
Check this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project. I think it can help you with configuring Webpack 4. Let me know..

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and let you know

Comment: Thank you so much! That example worked for me! If you want make it an aswer and I'll select it as the correct one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The config excerpt shared in your question seems correct.
Therefore, the problem could be even a typo.
If you want to share the project code to reproduce the issue I could help more.

Review my [**Webpack Demo**](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) on **GitHub** with working configs files as a starting point.

Read more about [configuring](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) Webpack.

Answer (score 9):

For me, it was the silly mistake of typing `module.export` instead of `module.exports` in the config file.

Answer (score 7):

`webpack.config.js`. Try something like:

```
const WEBPACK = require('webpack');
const PATH = require('path');

module.exports = {
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},
context: __dirname,
entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.jsx'] // app: ['./MY_FOLDER_INPUT/MY_FILE_INDEX.jsx']
},
output = {
    path: PATH.join(__dirname, '/MY_FOLDER_OUTPUT'),
    filename: 'index.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }
    ]
}
};
```

`package.json`. Add next `scripts`:

```
"scripts": 
{ 
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open", 
    "prod_build": "webpack --mode production" 
}
```

It should works

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately It doesn't work. It still shows that mode attribute has not been set and when I change entry path ('./js' for example) It throwns an error saying that nothing was found in ./src folder...

Comment: Have you copied my answer and runned it or have you adapt it to your code? I said it due to It works for me, so it so rare

Comment: Also try to change this inside `package.json`: `"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
  "prod_build": "webpack --mode production"
}`

Comment: I change entry and output parameters and error persists. Running dev server unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Ok, then, try Copy-Paste the code inside my answer, run also my script `build` and tell me if it works for you too. If it works is a good behaviour, else we should search other way to do that. I have updated answer for including `scripts` and for deleting `mode` inside `webpack`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem last week and I noticed that there was a whitespace character at the beginning of the filename (*" webpack.config.js"*) that is not visible in VS Code. Probably It was the real problem when I made the question.

Hope It helps

Comment: I accidentally named my webpack config file ".webpack.config.js", with a period in front. This answer forced me to really look at the name of my config file and realize the initial period didn't belong there. Thanks!